# Interesting Limit Behavior of Surface?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

As part of an exercise for a calculus class, students are asked to show that the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \left(\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}\right)$$

is 0 when approached from any linear trajectory $y = mx$. This is shown simply through L'Hopital's rule after $y$ has been substituted out.

Then students are asked to show that when the approach is $y=x^2$, the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$. This is again easily done by substitution.

My question is why would we get separate answers when considering all points around (0,0). To my understanding, we are saying that the limit is the value of the $f$ at the boundary points $H\subset U$ where $U$ is a neighborhood around $(0,0)$ with radius $r$ as that radius approaches 0. Clearly, for any $U$, there are two boundary points $H_i,H_j$ which lie on the parabola and would then have a different value from the rest of $H$. That clearly tells us that the limit doesn't exist, but not why it would appear to exist from linear approaches. Secondly, how can I rigorously show that there is no trajectory from which some function $G(x,y)$ has no limit at $(a,b)$?

Comment: Minor nitpick; if $U$ is an *open* neighbourhood (or just ball?) then its boundary $H$ is not contained in $U$, i.e. $H\subset U$ does not hold.

Comment: Find different limits (at least 2) by different paths is a rigorous way.

Comment: Also, it is very unclear to me what you mean by
$$\text{Clearly, for any $U$, there are two boundary points $H_i,H_j$ which lie on the parabola and would then have a different value from the rest of $H$.}$$
If $H$ is a circle centered at the origin then $x^2+y^2=c$ for all $x,y\in H$, for some positive real number $c$. It follows that on $H$ we have
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}
=\frac{(c-y^2)y}{(c-y^2)^2+y^2}
=\frac{cy-y^3}{y^4+(1-c)y^2+c^2}.$$
In particular $f$ takes on *infinitely many* different values on $H$, and takes on any value at most $4$ times.

Comment: The level curves $x^2 y/(x^4 + y^2) = C$ are pairs of parabolas tangent to the $x$-axis at the origin. When $C$ decreases, one of the two parabolas gets narrower. A line $y = m x$ intersects all the parabolas.

Answer (score 1):

I approach this type of problems by making a polar coordinates like substitution. If $$y=r\sin\theta$$ and $$x^2=r\cos\theta$$ you obtain $$x^4+y^2=r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta=r^2$$ and $$x^2y=r\cos\theta r\sin\theta$$
Then the function for which you are looking for the limit is $$\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}=\frac{r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}=\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
The limit when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, meaning $r\to 0$, exists only if the expression of $r$ and $\theta$ is independent of $\theta$ when $r\to 0$. In your case $$\lim_{r\to 0,\theta}\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin\theta\cos\theta$$ is clearly $\theta$ dependent. For parabola $$y=x^2$$ or $$r\sin\theta=r\cos\theta$$This means $$\sin\theta=\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$ Therefore the limit is $\frac 12$. For linear trajectories, $y=mx$. Square this and you get $$y^2=m^2x^2$$or $$r^2\sin^2\theta=r\cos\theta$$
In the limit $r\to 0$ you get $$\cos\theta=0$$so the limit of your expression is $0$.